# How to add curved view top left cornor in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation, uibezierpath, cgpoint

How to add uiview to top-left corner with curves.

I have done somethings like this

```
class curvedView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor.blue
        let y:CGFloat = 0
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height * 2))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.close()
        color.setFill()
        myBezier.fill()

    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    } 

}
```

But this create a curve in U shape but i want curve from x position 180 to Y position 250.

Any help would be so thankful.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you have a render of what is your desired output? Also, what does it look like with your current code?

Comment: @Larme i'm not able to upload any image to show.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these codes.it will help you

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewToRound.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this wont help me.